# mySQL Trigger on second table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Please help with this MySQL trigger - have searched and can not find problem with syntax.

Getting error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@v_index int DEFAULT 1; WHILE @v_index <= NEW.pt_number INSERT INTO Pat' at line 9

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_calls_insert_patients

AFTER INSERT ON Calls

FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

    DECLARE @v_index int DEFAULT 1;

    WHILE @v_index <= NEW.pt_number

        INSERT INTO Patients SET

        Patient_id = CONCAT(NEW.Calls_id, '-', @v_index),
        FK_Calls_id = NEW.Calls_id,
        update_by = "SYSTEM";

        SET @v_index := @v_index +1;

        END WHILE;

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dropping the @ in "DECLARE @v_index int DEFAULT 1;"